# What's the difference between a sequence and a collection in Clojure

Tags: collections, clojure, abstraction

I am a Java programmer and am new to Clojure. From different places, I saw sequence and collection are used in different cases. However, I have no idea what the exact difference is between them.

For some examples:

1) In Clojure's documentation for [Sequence](http://clojure.org/sequences#Sequences-The%20Seq%20interface):

```
The Seq interface
(first coll)
  Returns the first item in the collection. 
  Calls seq on its argument. If coll is nil, returns nil.
(rest coll)
  Returns a sequence of the items after the first. Calls seq on its argument. 
  If there are no more items, returns a logical sequence for which seq returns nil.
(cons item seq)
  Returns a new seq where item is the first element and seq is the rest.
```

As you can see, when describing the Seq interface, the first two functions (first/rest) use `coll` which seems to indicate this is a collection while the `cons` function use `seq` which seems to indicate this is a sequence.

2) There are functions called `coll?` and `seq?` that can be used to test if a value is a collection or a sequence. It is clearly collection and sequence are different.

3) In Clojure's documentation about '[Collections](http://clojure.org/data_structures#Data%20Structures-Collections)', it is said:

> Because collections support the seq function, all of the sequence
>   functions can be used with any collection

Does this mean all collections are sequences?

```
(coll? [1 2 3]) ; => true 
(seq? [1 2 3]) ; => false
```

The code above tells me it is not such case because `[1 2 3]` is a collection but is not a sequence.

I think this is a pretty basic question for Clojure but I am not able to find a place explaining this clearly what their difference is and which one should I use in different cases. Any comment is appreciated.

Comment: The biggest confusion stems from the fact that `seq?` does not test whether a "thing" is a "sequence" (or rather, a "sequential collection"), but whether it is a `seq` (i.e. something that can be manipulated by `first`, `next`, `rest`, technically a `clojure.lang.PersistentVector$ChunkedSeq`). Observe: `(def x [1 2])`, then: `(coll? x)` => true, `(sequential? x)` => true, `(seq? x)` => false, BUT! `(seq? (seq x))` => true

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Every sequence is a collection, but not every collection is a sequence.

The `seq` function makes it possible to convert a collection into a sequence. E.g. for a map you get a list of its entries. That list of entries is different from the map itself, though.

Comment: Interesting, in C# it's the other way round, every [collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92t2ye13(v=vs.110).aspx) is a sequence(it implements `IEnumerable`) but not every [sequence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0(v=vs.110).aspx) is a collection.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Whether this is different or the same as in Clojure depends upon which Clojure Java interface is considered equivalent to  .NET's `IEnumerable`, either `Seqable` or `ISeq`. Clojure collections implement `IPersistentCollection` which is a subtype of `Seqable`, and the only function required by `Seqable` is `seq` which I mentioned in my answer. Only implementations of `ISeq` (which is in turn a subtype of `IPersistentCollection`) are considered sequences in Clojure, but it could be argued that `Seqable` serves a similar purpose as .NET's `IEnumerable`.

Answer (score 27):

Any object supporting the core `first` and `rest` functions is a `sequence`.

Many objects satisfy this interface and every Clojure collection provides at least one kind of seq object for walking through its contents using the `seq` function.

So:

```
user> (seq [1 2 3])
    (1 2 3)
```

And you can create a sequence object from a `map` too

```
user> (seq {:a 1 :b 2})
    ([:a 1] [:b 2])
```

That's why you can use `filter`, `map`, `for`, etc. on `maps` `sets` and so on.

So you can treat many collection-like objects as sequences.

That's also why many sequence handling functions such as `filter` call `seq` on the input:

```
 (defn filter
  "Returns a lazy sequence of the items in coll for which
  (pred item) returns true. pred must be free of side-effects."
  {:added "1.0"
   :static true}
  ([pred coll]
   (lazy-seq
      (when-let [s (seq coll)]
```

If you call `(filter pred 5)`

```
  Don't know how to create ISeq from: java.lang.Long
                  RT.java:505 clojure.lang.RT.seqFrom
                  RT.java:486 clojure.lang.RT.seq
                 core.clj:133 clojure.core/seq
                core.clj:2523 clojure.core/filter[fn]
```

You see that `seq` call is the *is this object a sequence* validation.

Most of this stuff is in [Joy of Clojure](http://joyofclojure.com/) chapter 5 if you want to go deeper.

Comment: You need to also support the cons operation to be a sequence too

Comment: I have sweated on this enough. The Joy of Clojure Chapter 5 needs a rewrite.

Comment: 'Any object supporting the core first and rest functions is a sequence.' First & rest works on [1 2 3] but gives false on seq?.
(seq? [1 2 3]) ; => false
(first [1 2 3]) ; => 1
(rest [1 2 3]) ; => (2 3)

Answer (score 22):

Here are few points that will help understand the difference between **collection** and **sequence**.

1. "Collection" and "Sequence" are abstractions, not a property that can be determined from a given value.
2. Collections are bags of values.
3. Sequence is a data structure (subset of collection) that is expected to be accessed in a sequential (linear) manner.

The figure below best describes the relation between them:

[image]

You can read more about it [here](https://www.brainonfire.net/files/seqs-and-colls/main.html).

Comment: Venn diagram lists vector as a sequential. However `(seq? [1])` will return `false`, as indicated in the article itself.

Comment: @defhlt, `(seq? x)` checks if x implements ISeq or not. It is not used to check if x is sequential. Read more about it - https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/seq_q

Comment: Ok that you. I've found this answer useful as well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22439707/1056386

Answer (score 16):

In [*Clojure for the brave and true*](http://www.braveclojure.com/) the author sums it up in a really understandable way:

> The collection abstraction is closely related to the sequence
>   abstraction. All of Clojure's core data structures — vectors, maps,
>   lists and sets — take part in both abstractions.
>
> The abstractions differ in that the sequence abstraction is "about"
>   operating on members individually while the collection abstraction is
>   "about" the data structure as a whole. For example, the collection
>   functions `count`, `empty?`, and `every?` aren't about any individual
>   element; they're about the whole.

Comment: "All of Clojure's core data structures — vectors, maps, lists and sets — take part in both abstractions." That's actually wrong because "maps" and "sets" or not "sequences". Well, at least `sequential?` returns false for those, even for the ordered kinds.

Answer (score 7):

I have just been through Chapter 5 - "Collection Types" of "The Joy of Clojure", which is a bit confusing (i.e. the next version of that book needs a review). In Chapter 5, on page 86, there is a table which I am not fully happy with:

[image: Table 5.1 from the Joy of Clojure, 2nd ed.]

So here's my take (fully updated after coming back to this after a month of reflection).

## collection

It's a "thing", a collection of other things.

This is based on the function `coll?`.

- The function `coll?` can be used to test for this.
- Conversely, anything for which `coll?` returns true is a collection.

The `coll?` docstring says:

> Returns true if x implements `IPersistentCollection`

Things that are collections as grouped into three separate classes. Things in different classes are never equal.

- *Maps* Test using `(map? foo)`

  - Map (two actual implementations with slightly differing behaviours)
  - Sorted map. Note: `(sequential? (sorted-map :a 1)` ;=> false
- *Sets* Test using `(set? foo)`

  - Set
  - Sorted set. Note: `(sequential? (sorted-set :a :b))` ;=> false
- *Sequential collections* Test using `(sequential? foo)`

  - List
  - Vector
  - Queue
  - Seq: `(sequential? (seq [1 2 3]))` ;=> true
  - Lazy-Seq: `(sequential? (lazy-seq (seq [1 2 3])))` ;=> true

The Java interop stuff is outside of this:

- `(coll? (to-array [1 2 3]))` ;=> false
- `(map? (doto (new java.util.HashMap) (.put "a" 1) (.put "b" 2)))` ;=> false

## sequential collection (a "chain")

It's a "thing", a collection holding other things *according to a specific, stable ordering*.

This is based on the function `sequential?`.

- The function `sequential?` can be used to test for this.
- Conversely, anything for which `sequential?` returns true is a sequential collection.

The `sequential?` docstring says:

> Returns true if coll implements Sequential

Note: "sequential" is an adjective! In "The Joy of Clojure", the adjective is used as a noun and this is really, really, really confusing:

> "Clojure classifies each collection data type into one of three
>   logical categories or partitions: sequentials, maps, and sets."

Instead of "sequential" one should use a "sequential thing" or a "sequential collection" (as used above). On the other hand, in [mathematics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order) the following words already exist: "chain", "totally ordered set", "simply ordered set", "linearly ordered set". "chain" sounds excellent but no-one uses that word. Shame!

"Joy of Clojure" also has this to say:

> Beware type-based predicates!
>
> Clojure includes a few predicates with names like the words just
>   defined. Although they’re not frequently used, it seems worth
>   mentioning that they may not mean exactly what the definitions here
>   might suggest. For example, every object for which sequential? returns
>   true is a sequential collection, but it returns false for some that
>   are also sequential [better: "that can be considered sequential
>   collections"]. This is because of implementation details that may be
>   improved in a future version of Clojure [and maybe this has already been
>   done?]

## sequence (also "sequence abstraction")

This is more a concept than a thing: a series of values (thus ordered) which may or may not exist yet (i.e. a stream). If you say that a thing is a sequence, is that thing also necessarily a Clojure collection, even a sequential collection? I suppose so.

That sequential collection may have been completely computed and be completely available. Or it may be a "machine" to generate values on need (by computation - likely in a "pure" fashion - or by querying external "impure", "oracular" sources: keyboard, databases)

## seq

This is a thing: something that can be processed by the functions
`first`, `rest`, `next`, `cons` (and possibly others?), i.e. something that obeys the [protocol](https://clojure.org/reference/protocols) `clojure.lang.ISeq` (which is about the same concept as "providing an implementation for an interface" in Java), i.e. the system has registered function implementations for a pair *(thing, function-name)* [I sure hope I get this right...]

This is based on the function `seq?`.

- The function `seq?` can be used to test for this
- Conversely, a seq is anything for which `seq?` returns true.

Docstring for `seq?`:

> Return true if x implements ISeq

Docstring for `first`:

> Returns the first item in the collection. Calls seq on its argument.
>   If coll is nil, returns nil.

Docstring for `rest`:

> Returns a possibly empty seq of the items after the first. Calls seq
>   on its argument.

Docstring for `next`:

> Returns a seq of the items after the first. Calls seq on its argument.
>   If there are no more items, returns nil.

You call `next` on the seq to generate the next element and a new seq. Repeat until `nil` is obtained.

*Joy of Clojure* calls this a "simple API for navigating collections" and says "a seq is any object that implements the seq API" - which is correct if "the API" is the ensemble of the "thing" (of a certain type) and the functions which work on that thing. It depends on suitable shift in the concept of API.

A note on the special case of *the empty seq*:

```
(def empty-seq (rest (seq [:x])))

(type? empty-seq)                 ;=> clojure.lang.PersistentList$EmptyList

(nil? empty-seq)                  ;=> false ... empty seq is not nil
(some? empty-seq)                 ;=> true ("true if x is not nil, false otherwise.")

(first empty-seq)                 ;=> nil   ... first of empty seq is nil ("does not exist"); beware confusing this with a nil in a nonempty list!
(next empty-seq)                  ;=> nil   ... "next" of empty seq is nil
(rest empty-seq)                  ;=> ()    ... "rest" of empty seq is the empty seq
   (type (rest empty-seq))        ;=> clojure.lang.PersistentList$EmptyList
   (seq? (rest empty-seq))        ;=> true
   (= (rest empty-seq) empty-seq) ;=> true

(count empty-seq)                 ;=> 0
(empty? empty-seq)                ;=> true
```

## Addenda

### The function `seq`

If you apply the function `seq` to a thing for which that makes sense (generally a sequential collection), you get a seq representing/generating the members of that collection.

The docstring says:

> Returns a seq on the collection. If the collection is empty, returns
>   nil. (seq nil) returns nil. seq also works on Strings, native Java
>   arrays (of reference types) and any objects that implement Iterable.
>   Note that seqs cache values, thus seq should not be used on any
>   Iterable whose iterator repeatedly returns the same mutable object.

After applying `seq`, you may get objects of various actual classes:

- `clojure.lang.Cons` - try `(class (seq (map #(* % 2) '( 1 2 3))))`
- `clojure.lang.PersistentList`
- `clojure.lang.APersistentMap$KeySeq`
- `clojure.lang.PersistentList$EmptyList`
- `clojure.lang.PersistentHashMap$NodeSeq`
- `clojure.lang.PersistentQueue$Seq`
- `clojure.lang.PersistentVector$ChunkedSeq`

If you apply `seq` to a sequence, the actual class of the thing returned may be different from the actual class of the thing passed in. It will still be a sequence.

What the "elements" in the sequence are depends. For example, for maps, they are key-value pairs which look like 2-element `vector` (but their actual class is not really a vector).

### The function `lazy-seq`

Creates a thing to generate more things lazily (a suspended machine, a suspended stream, a [thunk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunk))

The docstring says:

> Takes a body of expressions that returns an ISeq or nil, and yields a
>   Seqable object that will invoke the body only the first time seq is
>   called, and will cache the result and return it on all subsequent seq
>   calls. See also - realized?"

### A note on "functions" and "things" ... and "objects"

In the Clojure Universe, I like to talk about "functions" and "things", but not about "objects", which is a term heavily laden with Java-ness and other badness. Mention of objects feels like shards poking up from the underlying Java universe.

What is the difference between function and thing?

It's fluid! Some stuff is pure function, some stuff is pure thing, some is in between (can be used as function and has attributes of a thing)

In particular, Clojure allows contexts where one considers keywords (things) as functions (to look up values in maps) or where one interpretes maps (things) as functions, or shorthand for functions (which take a key and return the value associated to that key in the map)

Evidently, functions are things as they are "[first-class citizens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_citizen)".

It's also contextual! In some contexts, a function becomes a thing, or a thing becomes a function.

There are nasty mentions of objects ... these are shards poking up from the underlying Java universe.

### For presentation purposes, a diagram of Collections

[image: Collections in Clojure]

Comment: `Sorted map. Note: (sequential? (sorted-map :a 1) ;=> false`, this line misses a trailing paren.
btw, this ans is so clear. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

For [`seq?`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/seq_q):

> Return true if x implements ISeq

For [`coll?`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/coll_q):

> Returns true if x implements IPersistentCollection

And I found [ISeq interface](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/ISeq.java) extends from IPersistentCollection in Clojure source code, so as Rörd said, every sequences is a collection.

Comment: @Jerry101 It's great that you'd like to add to the post, but suggested edit aren't the way to do it. To suggest improvements, it's best to add a comment explaining what should be fixed or updated. Also, please don't suggest the same edit to a post multiple times.