# Why does clojure.core/rest output a list when input is a vector?

Tags: clojure

Why does `clojure.core/rest` output a list when input is a vector?

This creates an unexpected effect:

```
(conj [1 2 3] 4)
; => [1 2 3 4]

(conj (rest [1 2 3]) 4)
; => (4 2 3)
```

I know that "it calls seq on its argument" from the [docs](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/rest) which creates this effect. I don't understand why this is the desired effect. As a naïve user, I would expect `(rest [1 2 3])` to behave like `(subvec [1 2 3] 1)`. I know I could just use `subvec` for my use case. For the sake of learning, I would like to understand the rationale of `rest`, and use cases where outputting a list is desirable (even when the input is a vector).

Comment: the rationale of `rest` is: `returns a possibly empty seq of the items after the first`, the issue is that conj'ng to a seq is different than to a vector, since the rationale of `conj` is to add to the underlying data structure in the "most efficient way" (seq prepend, vector append), at least that's how I understand it.

Comment: To go from `seq` (the thing, not the function) to vector, just use `(vec myseq)`. This may or may not involve computational cost. But it's a dynamic language, don't worry, be hacky. Comparions between vector and list works as expected, i.e.  `[1 2] is the same as `(1 2)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The output of `rest` is NOT a list, but a `seq`, which is an even lower level abstraction. From the [official documentation](https://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/rest) for `rest`:

> Returns a possibly empty **seq** of the items after the first. Calls **seq** on its
>   argument.

The confusion arises from the fact that both are printed between parens, but if you look closely, they are different:

```clj
user=> (list? (rest [1 2 3]))
false

user=> (seq? (rest [1 2 3]))
true
```

How it's a `seq` different from a `list`? `seq`s are implemented with an Interface that requires implementing `first`, `rest` and `cons`, but details are up to the collection implementation. For instance, vectors use their own implementation:

```clj
user=> (class (rest [1 2 3]))
clojure.lang.PersistentVector$ChunkedSeq

user=> (class (rest '(1 2 3)))
clojure.lang.PersistentList
```

List are an implementation that at least extends a basic Seq interface, and builds on top. For instance, `clojure.lang.PersistentList` implements the `Counted` interface which requires a constant-time version of `count`.

For a detailed description of the differences between Seqs and Lists, check these links:

- [Differences between a seq and a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22416387/differences-between-a-seq-and-a-list)
- https://clojure.org/reference/sequences

Comment: Thanks for making that distinction and correcting me - but my question still stands. Why design `rest` to output a `seq` when the input is a `vector`? From my perspective, `rest` is unnecessarily converting my dtype.

Comment: There is a Gist in Github that tries to track some of Rich Hickey's design decisions and touches a bit on `rest` here ( https://gist.github.com/reborg/dc8b0c96c397a56668905e2767fd697f#why-there-is-a-rest-and-a-next ). It seems to me that the design went on implementing `rest` like the function of the same name from Common Lisp, however, the singly-linked list from CL matches to the Seq abstraction in Clojure.

Comment: My abstractions get more general with height: so a sequence is a *higher* level abstraction than a list. That's the way class diagrams are usually drawn.

Answer (score 3):

You make a good case for `rest` on a vector returning a vector. The trouble is that `rest` is one of the fundamental operations on sequences, and a vector is not a sequence:

```
=> (seq? [1 2 3 4])
false
```

However, if `rest` can accept a `seq`able thing such as a vector, you could say that it ought to be able to return such.

What does it return?

```
=> (type (rest [1 2 3 4]))
clojure.lang.PersistentVector$ChunkedSeq
```

This gives every appearance of being a `subvec` wrapped in a `seq` call.

Answer (score 0):

> I know that "it calls seq on its argument"

That is correct. `Seqs` are implemented with an Interface (`ISeq`) that requires implementing `first`, `rest` and `cons`.

`rest` takes any `Seq'able` (any collection that implements `ISequable`). The reason for using this is efficiency and simplicity.

The way different collection works, the most efficient way of getting the `first` and `rest` is different.

Which is why when you convert one collection into a `seq`, it will come with the most efficient implementation on `rest` and the others.

I hope this was clear

Answer (score -2):

I agree that this behavior is unexpected and counterintuitive.  As a workaround, I created the `append` and `prepend` functions [in the Tupelo library](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo).

[From the docs](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo#adding-values-to-the-beginning-or-end-of-a-sequence), we see examples:

---

Clojure has the cons, conj, and concat functions, but it is not obvious how they should be used to add a new value to the beginning of a vector or list:

```
; Add to the end
> (concat [1 2] 3)    ;=> IllegalArgumentException
> (cons   [1 2] 3)    ;=> IllegalArgumentException
> (conj   [1 2] 3)    ;=> [1 2 3]
> (conj   [1 2] 3 4)  ;=> [1 2 3 4]
> (conj  '(1 2) 3)    ;=> (3 1 2)       ; oops
> (conj  '(1 2) 3 4)  ;=> (4 3 1 2)     ; oops

; Add to the beginning
> (conj     1  [2 3] ) ;=> ClassCastException
> (concat   1  [2 3] ) ;=> IllegalArgumentException
> (cons     1  [2 3] ) ;=> (1 2 3)
> (cons   1 2  [3 4] ) ;=> ArityException
> (cons     1 '(2 3) ) ;=> (1 2 3)
> (cons   1 2 '(3 4) ) ;=> ArityException
```

Do you know what conj does when you pass it nil instead of a sequence? It silently replaces it with an empty list: `(conj nil 5)` ⇒ `(5)` This can cause you to accumulate items in reverse order if you aren’t aware of the default behavior:

```
(-> nil
  (conj 1)
  (conj 2)
  (conj 3))
;=> (3 2 1)
```

These failures are irritating and unproductive, and the error messages don’t make it obvious what went wrong. Instead, use the simple `prepend` and `append` functions to add new elements to the beginning or end of a sequence, respectively:

```
(append [1 2] 3  )   ;=> [1 2 3  ]
(append [1 2] 3 4)   ;=> [1 2 3 4]

(prepend   3 [2 1])  ;=> [  3 2 1]
(prepend 4 3 [2 1])  ;=> [4 3 2 1]
```

Both `prepend` and `append` always return a vector result.

Comment: I was going to complain that your append and prepend have unpredictable performance, expecting vectors to have fast append and slow prepend. I guess I can't make that complaint, because they have predictably slow performance regardless of collection type.

Comment: If you are accumulating 5 million items, you should definitely plan your data structures carefully.  Perhaps even use a native Java object like ArrayList (preallocated, of course).  If you are accumulating 5 items, the data structure doesn't matter for speed.  In this case, correctness & ease-of-use are paramount.