# What is the difference between the functions seq?, sequential? and coll?

Tags: clojure

What is the difference between the functions seq? sequential? and coll?

I found some information scattered throughout the internet, but I think it would be better to centralize that information here.

Comment: http://www.brainonfire.net/files/seqs-and-colls/main.html

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`seq?` is a predicate that returns true if it's argument implements `ISeq` interface, which is to say it provides the methods `first`,`rest`,`cons`. See http://clojure.org/sequences.

```
(seq? [1 2])
false
(seq? (seq [1 2]))
true
```

`sequential?` is a predicate that returns true if it's argument implements `Sequential` interface. `Sequential` is a marker interface (no methods) and is a promise that the collection can be iterated over in a defined order (e.g. a list, but not a map).

```
(sequential? [])
true
(sequential? {})
false
```

`coll?` is a predicate that returns true if its argument implments `IPersistentCollection`. So for example the clojure data structures would return true, whereas native java data structures would not:

```
(coll? {:a 1})
true
(coll? (java.util.HashMap.))
false
```

Comment: Vectors provide `first`, `rest`, and `cons`, yet they aren't `seq?`?

Comment: @FeifanZ, these(`first`,`rest`,`cons`) functions first call [seq](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/seq) function for its argument. So if you use these functions for vector (`clojure.lang.PersistentVector`) which doesn't implement ISeq interface (seq? function return `false`), it means that you use these function for vector (`clojure.lang.PersistentVector$ChunkedSeq`) which implements ISeq interface(seq? return `true`).

Answer (score 9):

- `seq?` is true for any sequence.
- `sequential?` is true for any sequential (not associative)
  collection.
- `coll?` is true for any Clojure collection.

`seq?` implies `sequential?` implies `coll?`

```
=> ((juxt seq? sequential? coll?) ()) ; [true true true]
=> ((juxt seq? sequential? coll?) []) ; [false true true]
=> ((juxt seq? sequential? coll?) #{}); [false false true]
```

---

Inaccurate: `sequential?` is related to the others purely by convention - see [Kevin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22439707/1562315).